# Present ActionSheet in SwiftUI on iPad

Tags: swift, ipad, swiftui

I've gotten an ActionSheet to present just fine on an iPhone device. But it crashes for iPad. Says it needs the location for the popover. Has anyone had luck with this code? I'm using iOS 13 beta 3 and Xcode 11 beta 3. (This uses a version of presenting the ActionSheet not available in beta 2)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {
    @State var showSheet = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.showSheet.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Show")
            }
            .presentation($showSheet) { () -> ActionSheet in
                ActionSheet(title: Text("Hello"))

            }
        }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: I can duplicate this, along with the deprecated way. Worse, while it works on an iPhone (at least in the simulator, I don't have an iPhone yet running iOS 13) it yields *conflicting constraints*! My only question, seeing as I haven't used an `ActionSheet` before in `SwiftUI`, did it ever behave better in earlier betas? My best guess is to chalk it up as a beta bug and report it to Apple.

Comment: If someone is wondering why their basic sheet view isn't presenting on an iPad (but was fine on a phone, nested in a NavigationView), your view is there - to view it you need to swipe from the left edge to get it to show. To fix add .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle()) to your modal.

Comment: What I'm finding weird is that *some* of my action sheets present just fine on an iPad/Catalyst whereas others give this error. Anybody else had that? (without setting the popover sourceRect in either case)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally, as tested in iOS 13.4 this has been resolved, at least in the beta. The conflicting constraints warning persists, but the crash is gone. This is now the appropriate way to present an action sheet.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {
    @State var showSheet = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.showSheet.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Show")
            }
            .actionSheet(isPresented: $showSheet, content: { ActionSheet(title: Text("Hello"))
            })
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tested this on the iPad simulator running iOS 13.4 and nothing shows, just the '[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints' error. Of course the action sheet shows fine on an iPhone (iOS 13.4)

Comment: Yup. You can't attach it to the button unfortunately but only to the root view of your body. Then it'll show but it'll not be displayed correctly.

Answer (score 20):

Sadly, this bug has not been fixed for the final release of iOS 13. It was mentioned on the [developer forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/389028#389028), and I've filed a feedback for it (`FB7397761`), but for the time being one needs to work around it by using some other UI when `UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad`.

For the record, the (unhelpful) exception message is:

```
2019-10-21 11:26:58.205533-0400 LOOksTape[34365:1769883] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Your application has presented a UIAlertController (<UIAlertController: 0x7f826e094a00>) of style UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet from _TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingController… 
The modalPresentationStyle of a UIAlertController with this style is UIModalPresentationPopover. 
You must provide location information for this popover through the alert controller's popoverPresentationController. 
You must provide either a sourceView and sourceRect or a barButtonItem.  
If this information is not known when you present the alert controller, you may provide it in the UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate method -prepareForPopoverPresentation.'
```

As a workaround, this `popSheet` function will display a popover on the iPad and an `ActionSheet` everywhere else:

```swift
public extension View {
    /// Creates an `ActionSheet` on an iPhone or the equivalent `popover` on an iPad, in order to work around `.actionSheet` crashing on iPad (`FB7397761`).
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///     - isPresented: A `Binding` to whether the action sheet should be shown.
    ///     - content: A closure returning the `PopSheet` to present.
    func popSheet(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, arrowEdge: Edge = .bottom, content: @escaping () -> PopSheet) -> some View {
        Group {
            if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
                popover(isPresented: isPresented, attachmentAnchor: .rect(.bounds), arrowEdge: arrowEdge, content: { content().popover(isPresented: isPresented) })
            } else {
                actionSheet(isPresented: isPresented, content: { content().actionSheet() })
            }
        }
    }
}

/// A `Popover` on iPad and an `ActionSheet` on iPhone.
public struct PopSheet {
    let title: Text
    let message: Text?
    let buttons: [PopSheet.Button]

    /// Creates an action sheet with the provided buttons.
    public init(title: Text, message: Text? = nil, buttons: [PopSheet.Button] = [.cancel()]) {
        self.title = title
        self.message = message
        self.buttons = buttons
    }

    /// Creates an `ActionSheet` for use on an iPhone device
    func actionSheet() -> ActionSheet {
        ActionSheet(title: title, message: message, buttons: buttons.map({ popButton in
            // convert from PopSheet.Button to ActionSheet.Button (i.e., Alert.Button)
            switch popButton.kind {
            case .default: return .default(popButton.label, action: popButton.action)
            case .cancel: return .cancel(popButton.label, action: popButton.action)
            case .destructive: return .destructive(popButton.label, action: popButton.action)
            }
        }))
    }

    /// Creates a `.popover` for use on an iPad device
    func popover(isPresented: Binding<Bool>) -> some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(Array(buttons.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { (offset, button) in
                Group {
                    SwiftUI.Button(action: {
                        // hide the popover whenever an action is performed
                        isPresented.wrappedValue = false
                        // another bug: if the action shows a sheet or popover, it will fail unless this one has already been dismissed
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            button.action?()
                        }
                    }, label: {
                        button.label.font(.title)
                    })
                    Divider()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// A button representing an operation of an action sheet or popover presentation.
    ///
    /// Basically duplicates `ActionSheet.Button` (i.e., `Alert.Button`).
    public struct Button {
        let kind: Kind
        let label: Text
        let action: (() -> Void)?
        enum Kind { case `default`, cancel, destructive }

        /// Creates a `Button` with the default style.
        public static func `default`(_ label: Text, action: (() -> Void)? = {}) -> Self {
            Self(kind: .default, label: label, action: action)
        }

        /// Creates a `Button` that indicates cancellation of some operation.
        public static func cancel(_ label: Text, action: (() -> Void)? = {}) -> Self {
            Self(kind: .cancel, label: label, action: action)
        }

        /// Creates an `Alert.Button` that indicates cancellation of some operation.
        public static func cancel(_ action: (() -> Void)? = {}) -> Self {
            Self(kind: .cancel, label: Text("Cancel"), action: action)
        }

        /// Creates an `Alert.Button` with a style indicating destruction of some data.
        public static func destructive(_ label: Text, action: (() -> Void)? = {}) -> Self {
            Self(kind: .destructive, label: label, action: action)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank @marcprux!!! However, the code needs some modifications to run. Here what I did https://medium.com/@liemvo/solution-swiftui-actionsheet-crash-on-ipad-f0a5b3a7f755

Comment: I’m my case if crashes on:
DispatchQueue.main.async {
button.action?()
}
my fix is:
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1, execute: {
button.action?()
})

Comment: Thanks Roman!  Since I can't use the official fix because our devices are not yet at 13.4, I noticed that my iPad Actions were not dismissing without the delayed execution that Roman suggested!  That would have taken me hours to debug. Thanks!

Comment: I had a layout issue rather than a crash (ActionSheet appearing off screen on iPad), this answer put me in the right direction. However, I needed to specify some dimensions manually and change the attachmentAnchor amongst other things. Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/skl/db94520af2dd1317220c5eadb9de81da).

Answer (score 1):

Try this component, it will present an actionSheet on iPhone and a Popover on iPad and Mac.
https://github.com/AndreaMiotto/ActionOver

Answer (score 0):

Use the newer (iOS 15) `alert` modifier to present an alert in the center. That works well for iPad, unlike the ActionSheet that they never seem to fix.

```
.alert("Hello", isPresented: $showSheet) {
    // Add your buttons here
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Here's my workaround for the bug - it maintains the "actionsheet" functionality for iPhone devices but simply creates an "alert" style controller for iPad

It's simple enough for my case and may help others

```
    var preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
        preferredStyle = .alert
    }
    else{
        preferredStyle = .actionSheet
    }
    let cellMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Bought Item?", preferredStyle: preferredStyle)

    //Create actions
    //Add Actions to menu

    self.present(cellMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks. Just what I was looking for. Simple solution.

Comment: The question asks about ActionSheets in SwiftUI, not UIKit UIAlertController which have a different set of challenges.

Answer (score -5):

It is a known bug of beta. Just wait for a fix.

Comment: I wish I could say it is known. I submitted this bug in Feedback a long time ago with no response, and I don't see it listed as a known issue in Apple's release notes.